# AuthenticateAsync has been deprecated. How to use with Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: windows-phone, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-8.1

After about 3 hours I found out that in universal Windows Phone 8.1 apps the AuthenticateAsync-method has been deprecated.

When using it in Visual studio, at first, it is silent. When you try to run it, it says:

> AuthenticateAsync is unavailable for releases beginning with Windows
>   Phone 8.1. Instead, use AuthenticateAndContinue or
>   AuthenticateSilentlyAsync.

After another 2 hours, how hard I try, I cannot find a way to implement the example of the [Single-sign on](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/sso), it simply doesn't work.

AuthenticateAndContinue fails because the "remote procedure call failed"
SilentlyAsync returns the error, that the parameters are incorrect, but that is logical.

Do any of you guys know of a way to sign in, without using AuthenticateAsync?

Edit: When running anyway, it throws a not implemented Exception

Comment: It's just a warning, isn't it?  Try [#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When running AuthenticateAsync it throws a not implemented exception. I'm sorry. I should have said that.
P.S. I tried disabling 0618 and that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I assumed "deprecated: was just a compiler warning saying "we suggest you shouldn't use this API anymore".

I was wrong - it's apparently a hard error with the OP's Windows Phone SDK.  The new SDK doesn't support the old call; I doubt the Facebook SDK supports the new call.

SUGGESTED WORKAROUNDS:

1) Try using an older Windows Phone SDK (or, if possible, target your compile for an older version of the runtime).

2) Wrap your call in [Dispatcher.RunAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync)

- [WebAuthenticationBroken.AuthenticateAsync - NotImplementException](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3684f32d-ac61-4efe-9920-bea74e3d3661/webauthenticationbrokenauthenticateasync-notimplementexception?forum=winappswithcsharp)
- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
However when wrapping, I still get a not Implemented exception.
I have implemented it like this: await Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{ await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, loginUrl, endUri); });

I could try using an older version of the SDK, however, if I ever want to create a Windows version of the app, you need to do much more work.